# Distance banding with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to apply "distance banding". Instead of just simply sorting by distance, I would like the documents within 5 miles come first, followed by 5-10 mi documents, followed by 10-15mi, 15-25 mi, 25-50 mi, 50+mi. (And within each distance band they will be sorted by some other criteria).

I read on function_score decay, but I don't think it quite fits the purpose.

How would you suggest to go about it? boosting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is using the [`geo_distance`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geodistance-aggregation.html) aggregation to define the bands and then in each band use a [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) with some sort criteria.

It would look like this. You will need to change the location field (`location`) and the sort field (`name`) to match yours:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "rings": {
      "geo_distance": {
        "field": "location",
        "origin": "52.3760, 4.894",
        "ranges": [
          {
            "to": 5
          },
          {
            "from": 5, "to": 10
          },
          {
            "from": 10, "to": 15
          },
          {
            "from": 15, "to": 25
          },
          {
            "from": 25, "to": 50
          },
          {
            "from": 50
          }
        ]
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hits": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 5,
            "sort": {
              "name": "asc"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Val, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have another question. What if I want to sort first by relevance score, and then if scores are equal, by the "distance band" like above? Is it possible?